# How to draw a figure inside the box in latex beamer presentation?

Tags: pstricks

```
\documentclass[8pts]{beamer} 
\usepackage{amsmath,amsrefs,amsthm}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphics,graphicx}
\usetheme{Frankfurt}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}
\usepackage{tkz-berge}
\usepackage{pgf, tikz}
\usepackage{ragged2e}

\usepackage{setspace}\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{pst-all}
\usepackage{pstricks}

\def\bpsp{\begin{pspicture}}
\def\epsp{\end{pspicture}}

\setbeamerfont{description}{size=\small}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.3}
\def\B(G){\mathcal{T}_{\mathcal{B}_G}}

\newcommand\arrow[2]{\rotatebox{#1}{\scalebox{2}{\psline[linecolor=#2]{->}(0,0)(.1,0)}}}
\def\w{{\sf w}}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, automata}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\useoutertheme{miniframes}
\usefonttheme{serif}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
\mode<presentation>
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]


\begin{document}


    
\begin{figure}[h]
    
    \bpsp(1,3.5)
\rput(4,0.5){
            %\psgrid[subgriddiv=1,griddots=10,gridlabels=10pt](0,0)(10,4)
            
        \psline[linecolor=red](0,0)(2,1)(0,2)
            \psline[linecolor=green](0,0)(0,2)
            \rput(0,1){\arrow{90}{green}}
        
            \pscircle[linecolor=red,linestyle=dashed](4,1){.6}
                \psline[linecolor=red](2,1)(2,2.5)
                \psline[linecolor=red,linestyle=dashed](3.9,1.3)(2,1)(4,1)
                \psline[linecolor=red,linestyle=dashed](3.9,.7)(2,1)
    
            \psdot(0,0)\psdot(0,2)
            \psdot(2,2.5)\psdot(2,1)
        \pscurve[linestyle=dotted](1.5,3)(1.6,1)(3,0)(4,-.3)
        
            
            \rput(-.3,0){$x$}\rput(-.3,2){$y$}\rput(2.1,.75){$v$}
            \rput(3,2){$T$}
        }   
    
    \epsp
    \caption{The class of non-corona unicyclic $3$-colored digraphs whose inverses are unicyclic}\label{C1}
    \end{figure}
    \end{document}
```

When I compile this code, the figure goes outside. How we can draw it correctly inside the box? Please  help

Comment: Please help....

Comment: don't use abbreviations like \bpsp in questions. That makes it quite hard to read your code. Use the standard command names.

Comment: ok. But I have defined it earlier. Is there any problem now in compiling the code?

Comment: I didn't say that it doesn't compile but that it is more difficult to read. But actually it doesn't compile as \arrow is not defined. Clean up your example.

Comment: Ok. I have edited. You can see

Comment: Please help for the problem

Comment: stop to push. I have other things to do to. But your coordinates are wrong, you are drawing outside of the rectangle given by the pspicture. Start with something like `\bpsp(5,5)\rput(0,0.5)`.

Answer (score 1):

no need for `\rput`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{pst-all}
\setbeamerfont{description}{size=\small}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.3}
\def\B(G){\mathcal{T}_{\mathcal{B}_G}}

\newcommand\arrow[2]{\rotatebox{#1}{\scalebox{2}{\psline[linecolor=#2]{->}(0,0)(.1,0)}}}
\def\w{\textsf{w}}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\useoutertheme{miniframes}
\usefonttheme{serif}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
\mode<presentation>
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]

\begin{document}


\begin{figure}[h]    
\pspicture(5,3.5)
%\rput(4,0.5){
            %\psgrid[subgriddiv=1,griddots=10,gridlabels=10pt](0,0)(10,4)            
        \psline[linecolor=red](0,0)(2,1)(0,2)
            \psline[linecolor=green](0,0)(0,2)
            \rput(0,1){\arrow{90}{green}}
            \pscircle[linecolor=red,linestyle=dashed](4,1){.6}
                \psline[linecolor=red](2,1)(2,2.5)
                \psline[linecolor=red,linestyle=dashed](3.9,1.3)(2,1)(4,1)
                \psline[linecolor=red,linestyle=dashed](3.9,.7)(2,1)
            \psdot(0,0)\psdot(0,2)
            \psdot(2,2.5)\psdot(2,1)
        \pscurve[linestyle=dotted](1.5,3)(1.6,1)(3,0)(4,-.3)
            \rput(-.3,0){$x$}\rput(-.3,2){$y$}\rput(2.1,.75){$v$}
            \rput(3,2){$T$}
%        }   
 \endpspicture
 \caption{The class of non-corona unicyclic $3$-colored digraphs whose inverses are 
  unicyclic}\label{C1}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]